# I have a possible logic error while reversing an array

Tags: java

I've been trying to reverse an array using a for loop while not creating a new temporary array however the array only reverses halfway.

```
public void reverse() {
    int y = 0;
    int[] values = {10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1};

    for (int x = values.length - 1; x >= 0; x--) {
        int placeholder = values[x];
        values[y] = placeholder;
        y++;
        System.out.print(values[y] + " ");
    }
}
```

Right now the method returns the values of the array. However, the value is

```
"1 2 3 4 5 5 4 3 2 1"
```

The desired output is,

```
"1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10".
```

Comment: What happens to the original number in `values[y]`?

Comment: I was under the impression that the value of the placeholder variable is assigned to the values array at the new desired index.

Comment: Running the code results in `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: @tpad There's no assignment of `values[x]` (the values array at the new desired index).

Answer (score 1):

You're reassigning some of the previously overwritten values back to the array (so you lose half of the values). Instead, you should loop to half the length of the array and swap corresponding elements.

```java
for (int i = 0, j = values.length - 1; i < j; i++, j--) {
    int temp = values[i];
    values[i] = values[j];
    values[j] = temp;
}
System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(values));
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `x >= 0`, the loop should be terminated as soon as `x` and `y` meet or surpass each other, or swapped values would be swapped one more time and back into their original slots.

Also did you forget to assign `values[y]` to `values[x]` within the loop body?

```java
public void reverse(int[] values)
{
    if (values.length == 0) return;
    
    int x = values.length - 1;
    int y = 0;

    while (x > y)
    {
        // swapping
        int temp = values[x];
        values[x] = values[y];
        values[y] = temp;

        // moving ptrs
        x--;
        y++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes,you are not supposed to directly assign, you should swap, otherwise the value to the left of the equal sign will be overwritten.Another way is to find a variable to record the value on the left side of the equal sign and assign it to the right side.